# What is the difference between the races elf and high elf?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I am without a computer right now but I keep following the lotro news.
I read that with the Mordor Expansion it will be added a new race: High Elf.

What are the differences between the Elves and the High Elves races?

Comment: Are you asking what's the difference lore-wise or how they differ in-game?

Comment: I was asking how they differ in game

Answer (score 2):

Summary gleaned from [Learning LOTRO, Lesson Ten, Racial Traits](https://gamerreverie.blogspot.com/2020/04/learning-lotro-lesson-ten-racial-traits.html):

Elf:

- Silvan Shadows: Min. level 13; +Stealth.
- Friend of Man: Min. level 13; Fate boost.
- Tactics and Conviction Bonus: Min. level 19; Fellowship maneuvers.
- Elf Bow-damage Bonus: level 25; Bow damage.
- Return to Rivendell: Min. level 29; travel to Rivendell
- Elf One-handed Sword-damage Bonus: Min. level 30; Weapon damage.
- Virtuous Elf: Min. level 35; Purchaseable virtues.
- Power of the Eldar: Min. level 35; Fellowship power.
- Eldar's Grace: Min. level 35; Parry boost.

High Elf

- Grace of the Firstborn: Min. level 13; Speed boost.
- Wrath of the Firstborn: Min.level 19; Fellowship damage.
- Grace of Valinor: Min. level 25; Out-of-Combat revive/rez ally.
- Those Who Remain: Min. level 29; Will boost.
- Travel to Caras Galadhon: Min level 32; Travel to Caras Galadhon
- Enmity of Darkness. Min. level 35; Light damage boost
- Glory of the First Age: Min. level 38; Paralyze enemies.
- Blade Dancer: Min. at level 42; Sword skills.
- Virtuous High Elf: Min. level 60; Virtue boosts.

The [High Elf starter quests](http://razorskiss.net/2017/07/high-elf-in-lord-of-the-rings-online-a-review/) are entirely new and feature starting at the Battle of Dagorlad and featuring Sauron's defeat by Isildur.  See also [this preview](http://www.containsmoderateperil.com/blog/2017/7/2/lotro-high-elf-preview).

High Elves [are able to roll every class except for Beornings and Burglars. High Elves look slightly different (particularly their hair)](https://massivelyop.com/2017/07/01/take-your-first-gander-at-lotros-high-elves/).  Whereas an elf can play as a Champion, Guardian, Hunter, Lore-master, Minstrel, Rune-keeper, or Warden, a High Elf can also play as a Captain.

High Elves have [cool animation changes](https://www.lotro.com/forums/showthread.php?661809-Are-High-Elves-worth-it) including a `/dance3` emote that is somewhat like a ballet dance move.  When falling, they do it very gracefully with a rolling animation.

[Elf](https://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Elf) and [High Elf](https://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/High_Elf) have the same base stat adjustments:

- -20 Max Morale
- -60 Non-combat Morale Regen
- +15 Agility
- Fate -7
- +1% resistance to disease
- +1% resistance to poison

This YouTube video may be of interest: [High Elves vs. Elves in LOTRO - What's the Difference?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enxiHNPlLIY).